# In what cases does Python complex exponentiation throw an OverflowError?

Tags: python, floating-point, complex-numbers

I’m trying to figure out the pattern here:

```
>>> 1e300 ** 2
OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
>>> 1e300j ** 2
OverflowError: complex exponentiation
>>> (1e300 + 1j) ** 2
OverflowError: complex exponentiation
>>> (1e300 + 1e300j) ** 2
(nan+nanj)
```

The behavior seems to be not only unspecified in theory, but also weird in practice! What explains this?

Comment: Also, `(1e300+1e300j) ** 100  ==>  (nan+nanj);
(1e300+1e300j) ** 101 ==>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: complex exponentiation`

Comment: 1e300 is a float value, so it does not get autopromotion. This works tho: `(1*10**300)**2`

Comment: Jason: if you have time to open an issue on http://bugs.python.org, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: What is the correct result? What is the bug?

Comment: @drewk: Not sure whether I'd call it a bug (it probably wouldn't make sense to fix this for Python 2.7, for example), but the inconsistency of sometimes raising an exception and sometimes returning nans and infinities is disturbing.  Ideally it should be doing either one or the other in all cases (I'd go for the exception, personally).  It would be good to fix this for Python 3.4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A look at the [source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b7a9c14fc082/Objects/complexobject.c#l509) for complex exponentiation shows that Python only checks for overflow at the end of the computation. Also, there's a special case for small integer exponents that uses exponentiation by squaring, which involves complex multiplication.

```
r.real = a.real*b.real - a.imag*b.imag;
r.imag = a.real*b.imag + a.imag*b.real;
```

This is the formula for complex multiplication. Note the following:

```
a.real*b.real - a.imag*b.imag
```

When `a` and `b` are very large, this becomes floating-point infinity minus floating-point infinity, which is `nan`. The `nan` results propagate, and after a few operations, the result is `(nan+nanj)`. `Py_ADJUST_ERANGE2` only sets `errno` if it sees an infinity, so it misses the overflow and goes on its way.

In summary, Python only checks the end result for overflow, not intermediate values, and this causes it to miss the overflow in the middle because it's all `nan`s by the end. The expressions that do raise `OverflowError` do so because they never try to subtract infinities, so the error is spotted by the end. It doesn't look like a deliberate design decision; you could fix it by changing the way the overflow check works.

Comment: -1: This is a pretty good answer, but the statement `The expressions that do raise OverflowError do so because they never try to subtract infinities, so the error is spotted by the end.` is completely false.

Comment: @thewolf: Really? What's the issue?

Comment: I suspect @thewolf interpreted “The expressions that do raise `OverflowError`” to refer to a general case or a general statement about Python operation rather than the specific examples in this question.

Comment: Ah. No, I'm just talking about the ones in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I'm pretty sure I figured this out.

First, I noticed something that seemed somewhat ridiculous:

```
>>> (1e309j)**2
(nan+nanj)
>>> (1e308j)**2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: complex exponentiation
```

Interesting. Maybe this doesn't have to do with complex exponentiation at all.

```
>>> (1e309)**2
inf
>>> (1e308)**2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
```

Even more interesting. Let's see what Python thinks of `1e309` and `1e308`:

```
>>> (1e308)
1e+308
>>> (1e309)
inf
```

Finally,

```
>>> (1e309)**2
inf
>>> (1e309j)**2
(nan+nanj)
```

And

```
>>> (float('inf') + 1j) ** 2
(nan+nanj)

>>> (1e309j)
infj
>>> (1e309j)**2
(nan+nanj)
```

Any manipulations of `inf` gives us `inf`. It looks like the implementation of complex numbers (`a + bi`) are less inclined to give `inf`, and more to give `(nan + nanj)`. So, something that would normally return `inf` instead returns `(nan + nanj)` I'm not sure why this is, maybe someone with a better understanding of Python's `inf` and `nan` could jump in.

In short, numbers stop overflowing eventually, and start returning `inf`. Calculations with `inf` are easy, but calculations with numbers close to it aren't! That's why `1e309**2` works while `1e308 ** 2` doesn't. When paired with complex numbers, this (for whatever reason) gives `(nan + nanj)`. I only found this out by playing with the console -- I'd love to see a more thorough explanation!

Edit: @user2357112 gives a much better reason for this. The way complex exponents are calculated can include a calculation of `inf - inf`, which returns `nan`. I'll leave this up to display the pattern, but his answer gives the reasoning.

---

As a side-note, I found this funny:

```
>>> (float('inf') + 1j) ** 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: complex exponentiation
>>> (float('inf') + 1j) 
(inf+1j)
```

Comment: This isn't it. I've posted the full analysis in an answer.

Comment: @user2357112 actually, your explanation is consistent with almost all of my answer -- you just give a more concrete explanation of why we are getting `(nan - nanj)`

Answer (score 0):

Python integer values can autopromote to a long for arbitrary precision:

```
>>> (10**300)**2
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Float values overflow because of the limitation of the [IEEE floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point):

```
>>> float(10**300)**2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
```

The component of a Python complex is a class of float, subject to the same overflow:

```
>>> isinstance(complex(1).real,float)
True
>>> isinstance(complex(1).imag,float)
True
```

Take the usual max [double precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format#Double-precision_examples) value:

```
>>> max_double=1.7976931348623157e+308
```

Do most steps that increase that value in the range of the floating point range and you get `inf`:

```
>>> max_double*10
inf
>>> max_double*max_double
inf
>>> max_double*max_double*max_double*max_double
inf
>>> max_double++10**(308-15)
inf
```

If outside of the FP window, the mantisa and exponent do not change:

```
>>> md+10**(308-17)
1.7976931348623157e+308
>>> max_double**1.0000000000000001
1.7976931348623157e+308
```

Overflow can be seen:

```
>>> max_double**1.000000000000001
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
```

But as [stated in the documents](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.OverflowError), it is inconsistently applied:

> Because of the lack of standardization of floating point exception
>   handling in C, most floating point operations also aren’t checked.

Which can be seen here:

```
>>> (1e300+1e300j)*(1e300+1e300j)
(nan+infj)
>>> (1e300+1e300j)**2
(nan+nanj)
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question. Why doesn't `(1e300+1e300j)**2` raise an `OverflowError`?

Comment: Because the intermediate values overflow. Try `1.7976931348623157e+308*1.0000000000001`

Comment: @drewk I down-voted this because it seemed totally irrelevant to the question. Now that I see its relevance, I'd like to change my vote but I can't unless you edit the answer! Your call.

Comment: How is this relevant? We *know* that floats overflow. We *know* that complex numbers are represented with two floating-point numbers. Python is supposed to raise an `OverflowError` when overflow happens in floating-point exponentiation. The question is asking why `(1e300+1e300j)**2` *doesn't* raise the expected `OverflowError`.