# Python: Why are sufficiently large floating point values infinite?

Tags: python, floating-point

```
>>> 1e100000000
inf
>>> 1000000 ... [400 zeroes snipped] ... 000000
1000000 ... [400 zeroes snipped] ... 000000
>>> 1000000 ... [400 zeroes snipped] ... 000000.0
inf
```

Why does Python decide that large floats are infinite? If the representation can't represent that value, I would expect it to give an error, like this does:

```
>>> 10.0 ** 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
OverflowError: (34, 'Numerical result out of range')
```

Why is the first case silent if the second case complains?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you tried to create a floating point number that is larger that the largest value representable in a floating point value.

See the [`sys.float_info` named tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.float_info); `sys.float_info.max` is the largest value representable in such values. Python floats, unlike Python integers, have an upper limit determined by your OS and hardware platform, integers are limited by your available memory.

On my Mac, that maximum value is:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.float_info.max
1.7976931348623157e+308
```

So a 1 with 308 zeros is representable, but a 2 with that many zeros is not:

```
>>> float('1' + '0' * 308)
1e+308
>>> float('2' + '0' * 308)
inf
```

Floats are limited because floating point arithmetic is typically handled by the floating point unit on your CPU, and Python's float type is limited to what that piece of hardware can handle.

Defining a float *literal* is a different operation from applying arithmetic to a floating point value; the first is determined at compile time, the latter is determined at *runtime*. A literal could only produce a `SyntaxError` exception, while at runtime you can throw other exceptions. But throwing a syntax error for a float literal that on other platforms could still be valid is not really an option, so instead of an exception you get `float('inf')` instead.

The [Python specification for float literals](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#floating-point-literals) only declares that the permitted range is implementation dependent:

> The allowed range of floating point literals is implementation-dependent.

There is a point where calculations too return `float('inf')` because once you have reached infinity calculations are easy (most cases just give you a form of infinity back), but close to infinity you get overflows instead. The [float exponentiation implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/22790c4f3b16/Objects/floatobject.c#l809) simply uses the [C `pow()` function](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pow), and the exception is thrown when that function reports an overflow.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question as I read it: the OP is asking why one operation returns `inf` while the other raises an exception.  It would have been perfectly possible for the Python devs to have `10.0 ** 1000` return infinity instead of raising, or for parsing of a `1e1000` literal to raise instead of producing an infinity.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: wheee, and `(1e309)**2` gives `float('inf')` while `(1e308)**2` (**one zero smaller**) gives `OverflowError`. See [In what cases does Python complex exponentiation throw an OverflowError?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18243270) That's because `1e309` is already infinity, of course.

Comment: Yes, but that's because `1e309` is already an infinity.  There are some open bug reports on this somewhere, but it's hard to fix without breaking backwards compatibility.

Comment: Interesting. Why is throwing a SyntaxError exception not an option? Are SyntaxErrors banned from varying by machine?

Comment: @EliRose: the python bytecode cache file is meant to be usable cross-platform. You can create it on a 64-bit machine and take it to a limited machine with smaller floats without issue, *and vice versa*.

Comment: @EliRose: SyntaxErrors are thrown at compile time; if floating point sizes where to be tested then you'd not be able to create the bytecache on the limited machine.