# complex("inf") ** 1 throws OverflowError

Tags: python, infinity, complextype

In Python 3.10.9, this example raises `OverflowError: complex exponentiation`:

```
complex("inf") ** 1
```

But this works, evaluating to `(nan+nanj)`:

```
complex("inf") ** 2
```

Why does it work this way? Is there a bug to report?

Comment: It seems this relates to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243270/in-what-cases-does-python-complex-exponentiation-throw-an-overflowerror)

Comment: The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18243849/1442918)  there seems to indicate why it's inconsistent: it does all the intermediate steps, then checks if any of them are infinite, and if it is, throws an OverflowError.  With ** 2, the intermediate values become NaN, which does not trigger the error.  I think this could be handled better.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In what cases does Python complex exponentiation throw an OverflowError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243270/in-what-cases-does-python-complex-exponentiation-throw-an-overflowerror)

Comment: Basically, unintentional side effect of the algorithm.

Answer (score -3):

```
import math

Infinity = complex(math.inf, 0) # or complex("inf") whichever returns (inf+0j)
print(Infinity)

result0 = Infinity ** 2
print(result0) # prints (nan+nanj)

result1 = Infinity ** 1
print(result1) # prints OverflowError: complex exponentiation
```

Hey Petr !
You got that because the complex class does not support the ** operator for infinite values.

The ** operator is used for exponentiation in Python.
When applied to complex numbers, it raises the first number to the power of the second number.
However, if either of the numbers is infinite, the result is undefined.

This programming behavior is defined by the IEEE 754 floating-point standard.
In this standard, some rules govern the operations involving "inf" and "nan," and these rules are implemented consistently across most programming languages, including Python.

complex("inf") ** 1:

In this case, you are raising infinity to the power of 1.
According to the rules, anything raised to the power of 1 remains unchanged.
So, the result is inf (positive infinity). So python is unable to calculate it here and gives you a erro.

complex("inf") ** 2:

Here, you are squaring infinity.
According to the rules, this results in a complex number with a real part of "inf" and an imaginary part of "nan"

However, Python chooses to represent undefined values with the special value NaN (Not a Number).
Therefore, the result of complex(math.inf, 0) ** 2 is (nan+nanj).

So, there is no hidden bug here related to these operations.

Comment: So complex numbers have a real and imaginary part, So when either of them have infinite as the value. python cannot calculate right ? so **2 gives a real part nan i and a complex part nan j

Comment: Can someone pls tell me what in my thinking process is wrong here! Any feedback is appreciated !

Comment: I don't know specifically why you are being downvoted, but if `complex('inf')` is representable in Python then you can't just handwave away `complex('inf') ** 1` raising an error, as it should be a no-op.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I downvoted the answer because of what you just wrote. Also, the second case does not make sense: even if complex("inf") ** 2 is interpreted as complex("inf") * complex("inf"), then the answer, according to the table that DataAngel referenced, should be inf+0j and not nan+nanj. So the second part is handwaving, as well. So, all in all, neither of the cases can be argued for with the information on the site that DataAngel references in their comment.

Comment: I correct myself: it should be inf+nanj: (inf + 0j) * (inf + 0j) = inf ** 2 + 2 * inf * 0j + 0j ** 2 = inf + nanj (as inf * 0 in the j term, according to the referenced table, is nan).